# Apache permissions to execute the exec function

Tags: php, linux, apache, exec, centos

I've been trying to run this php code on CentOS:

```
<?php

$command = "diff file1 file2 > file3";
exec($command, $output, $error_code);

if ($error_code != 0) {
    echo "Error: $error_code";
}

?>
```

And it always echoes "Error: 1". Error 1 is "Operation not permitted" http://www.pegasoft.ca/resources/boblap/99_b.html. It looks like apache has no permissions to do certain things, right? How can I fix that?

Comment: try `ps aux | grep http` to ensure the apache running as user apache

Comment: I think it is http://img704.imageshack.us/i/isit.png/ what happened to that reply and those comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh >***_*__*_***<

I had this line at the end of my script:

```
exec("rm -f /var/local/out/upload/example_word/word/diff.diff");
```

The file was created and then deleted... That's why I could never see it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you're not using the right command. You're running $command like in a terminal, so you need to add a command indicating that you have permission. I think that on CentOS it's su. In Ubuntu, for example, you would do sudo -command-.

So try to add su before diff.

Edit:

You should check here for proper usage of su:
http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/BecomingRoot